# Retrieving record from database in Java by using select option tag

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I want to retrieve record from database by clicking on the option selected from drop down list and it as a table on the web page. But after implementing following code the web page is blank now what should I do? Any type of help will be appreciable. Here is my `index.jsp` page:

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="f1" action="portal" method="POST">
            <h3>Name of the Book : </h3>
                <select name="book" id="book">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="1">The Pilgrims Progress</option>
                    <option value="2">Robinson Crusoe</option>
                    <option value="3">Gullivers Travels</option>
                    <option value="4">Clarissa</option>
                    <option value="5">Tom Jones</option>
                    <option value="6">The Life and Opinions of Tristram Shandy, Gentleman</option>
                    <option value="7">Emma</option>
                    <option value="8">Frankenstein</option>
                    <option value="9">Nightmare Abbey</option>
                    <option value="10">The Narrative of Arthur Gordon Pym of Nantucket</option>
                    <option value="11">Sybil</option>
                    <option value="12">Jane Eyre</option>
                    <option value="13">Wuthering Heights</option>
                    <option value="14">Vanity Fair</option>
                    <option value="15">David Copperfield</option>
                    <option value="16">The Scarlet Letter</option>
                    <option value="17">Moby-Dick</option>
                    <option value="18">Alices Adventures in Wonderland</option>
                    <option value="19">The Moonstone</option>
                    <option value="20">Little Women</option>
                    <option value="21">Middlemarch</option>
                </select>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my servlet page for retrieving data from database

```java
package com;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class portal extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            String book = request.getParameter("book");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql", "root", "password");
            PreparedStatement pt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from book where Book_Name = ?");
            pt.setString(1, book);
            out.print("<table width = 75%>");
            out.print("<center><h1>Welcome To The Portal</h1></center>");
            ResultSet rs = pt.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsd = rs.getMetaData();
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print("<tr>");
                out.print("<td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(1) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(1) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(2) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(2) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(3) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(3) + "</td></tr>");
                out.print("<tr><td>" + rsmd.getColumnName(4) + "</td>");
                out.print("<td>" + rs.getString(4) + "</td></tr>");
                RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("logout.jsp");
                rd.include(request, response);
            }
            out.println("</table>");
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            out.println(e);
        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the
    // + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request
     *            servlet request
     * @param response
     *            servlet response
     * @throws ServletException
     *             if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException
     *             if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

now I don't know where I miss something.

Comment: Can not reproduce the problem.

Comment: why do you include logout.jsp for each row found?

Comment: 1. Check if you are getting any data from the database. 2. Try to produce a valid HTML; in your `while` loop you are not doing this.

Comment: i'm including logout.jsp because i don't wnat to write that code again again on every page..

Comment: produce a valid html means? what i have to do?

Comment: Now you corrected it, I think (before I wrote the comment your tags were not closed correctly). But I am not sure whether you want to repeat the name of columns for every record you find. And as the user Nicolas suggested you should put your dispatcher call outside of the loop.

Comment: i've already corrected it.. thanku soo much for the help ujulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use your servlet as a controller that control the data in your application and not as a vue where you write html tags

this example may help you :

Firstly, create a serialisable java class where you put communicate with database :

```java
public class BookData implements Serializable {

    private String ISBN;
    private String titre;
    private String auteur;
    private int ID;
    private String editeur;

    // ADD GETTER AN SETTER METHODS

    public BookData(String titre, String auteur, int ID, String editeur, String ISBN) {
        this.titre = titre;
        this.auteur = auteur;
        this.ID = ID;
        this.editeur = editeur;
        this.ISBN = ISBN;
    }

    public List<BookData> loadData(String book) {
        List<BookData> actorList = new ArrayList<BookData>();

        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement ps = null;

        ResultSet rs = null;

        String url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/DATABASENAME";// CHANGE
        String name = "NAME";// CHANGE
        String pw = "PWD";// CHANGE
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";

        Connection connexion = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, pw);

            String q = "Select * from book where Book_Name ='" + book + "'";
            Statement commande = connexion.createStatement();
            rs = commande.executeQuery(q);

            while (rs.next()) {
                BookData bk = new BookData(rs.getString("Book_Title"), rs.getString("Book_Author"), rs.getInt("ID"),
                        rs.getString("Publisher"), rs.getString("ISBN"));/* CHANGE COLUMN NAMES */

                actorList.add(bk);
            }

            return actorList;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                rs.close();
                connexion.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly the servlet :

```java
public class EXAMPLE_SERVLET extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String option = request.getParameter("book");

        BookData dao = new BookData();
        List<BookData> list = dao.loadData(option);

        request.setAttribute("booklist", list);

        RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

then the JSP ((test.jsp))

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>titre</th> //...COLUMNS
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="employee" items="${booklist}">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 110px; color: #3278b3;">${employee.titre}</td>
                //...ROWS
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but i don't want to do this i only wanted that if i select a option at web page it will retrieve the data from databse and show it to me as it is of that particular option but i'm getting blank page only , even if my table tag is working i'm getting the message "Welcome to the portal" in center but there is no output the value of option tag

Comment: using tags in servlet is discouraged and this is MVC architecture it is the recommanded to work with

Answer (score 0):

i solved my question thanks to everyone who helped me but not i get it where i was doind a mistake it was in option tag value attribute i took the value as 1 , 2 and 3 .. so on but it should be same as the text and in servlet page i've changed the while loop to if & else so it is working fine.. thanku soo much for all your help